# The Select Query does not show the data in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

I have 2 datagridview i need to take the data from one to anther with rowindex and query I have a problem the query not show the data its write null

```
void dataGridViewDoses_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    RowIndex = int.Parse(e.RowIndex.ToString());
    int categoryId = (int)this.comboBoxCategoryOrders.SelectedValue;
    dataGridViewDoseOrders.DataSource = Dose.GetDoseOrder(categoryId, RowIndex);
}

public static DataTable GetDoseOrder(int CategoryID, int RowIndex)
{
    string strSql = string.Format("SELECT DoseName, Price, CategoryID, ImageUrl FROM TblDose WHERE(CategoryID = {0})AND(RowIndex = {1})", CategoryID, RowIndex);
    return DAL.GetDataTable(strSql);
}
```

CategoryID and RowIndex is show true value but not show the data

Comment: If you try that query in whichever database are you using, using the exact values passed by your program for CategoryID and RowIndex did you get any result?

Comment: in the data the result is ok but in datagridview is show me null

Comment: Check for the blank space in ')AND(' - possible syntax error. Best regards,

Comment: Do you have __AutoGenerateColumns__ set to True (the default) for the grid __dataGridViewDoseOrders__?

Comment: the problem with e.RowIndex this is not give me the row from the data but if i delete the RowIndex from the query and save only CategoryID this give me all the rows

Comment: @Steve i dont have AutoGenerateColumns set

Comment: It is not clear what RowIndex is in your table TblDose

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns should be set to True by default in the Form Designer. Whithout it no rows in the Dose grid.

Comment: this show row without data

Comment: @Steve the problem with e.RowIndwx , i think that i take list with all the category and than i take the rowindex from the list and i will put the select row in the datagridview